# Copying directory with conditions

Tags: go, directory, copy

I have a task to copy directory, and paste it in an another folder with conditions using Go.
For example I have a directory tree such like that:

project

---app(where to copy)

---packages(from where copy)

------process

---------client01

------------build(folder)

---------------main.go

---------------config.json

---------------someFolder

------------someText.txt

---------client02

------------test4

---------------build

------------testProject

---------client04

------------projectX

------------test.go
The condition is copying only directory which only has child folder with name "build" and in the copied parent folder should be only build folder within its files.

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path"
)
// File copies a single file from src to dst
func File(src, dst string) error {
    var err error
    var srcfd *os.File
    var dstfd *os.File
    var srcinfo os.FileInfo

    if srcfd, err = os.Open(src); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer srcfd.Close()

    if dstfd, err = os.Create(dst); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer dstfd.Close()

    if _, err = io.Copy(dstfd, srcfd); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if srcinfo, err = os.Stat(src); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return os.Chmod(dst, srcinfo.Mode())
}
// Dir copies a whole directory recursively
func Dir(src string, dst string) error {
    //var files Files
    var err error
    var fds []os.FileInfo
    var srcinfo os.FileInfo

    if srcinfo, err = os.Stat(src); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if fds, err = ioutil.ReadDir(src); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err = os.MkdirAll(dst, srcinfo.Mode()); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, fd := range fds {
        srcfp := path.Join(src, fd.Name())
        dstfp := path.Join(dst, fd.Name())


        if fd.IsDir() && srcfp == src + "/build"  {
            //files = append(files, dstfp)
            println(srcfp)
            if err = Dir(srcfp, dstfp); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            if err = File(srcfp, dstfp); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        } else if fd.IsDir() && srcfp == srcfp {
            if err = Dir(srcfp, dstfp); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        } else {
            if err = File(srcfp, dstfp); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }

    }
    return nil
}

func main () {
    err := Dir("./packages", "./app")
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
    }
}
```

I expected a result directory tree in app:

project

---app(where to copy)

------client01

---------build

------------main.go

------------config.json

------------someFolder

------test4

---------build

For instance, test4 and client01 copied because it has "build" child-folder, and it copies only build folder

But I got that result directory tree:
project

---app

------process(that folder should not be copied)

---------client01

-----------build

--------------main.go

--------------config.json

Answer (score 0):

So far i can tell, you only need to change this line : `err := Dir("./packages", "./app")` into : `err := Dir("./packages/process", "./app")`

If you want something else, let it know. Because i am guessing what the real problem is.

Comment: I found the problem, the solution. Sorry, for incomprehensible question. It is my first question in stackoverflow. The solution is here https://github.com/malikov0216/lernaDirectoryTreeReplacer. May be it will be useful for someone